# Certain mac system hotkeys don't work on PC keyboard.

Tags: mac, hotkeys, osx-mavericks, mirroring, projector

I am using a Mac mini with a typical PC usb keyboard (not a Mac keyboard). I am on OSX 10.9.3.

According to [this apple support web page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343), Cmd+F1 should toggle 'mirror displays', but it doesn't work. I am assuming that it has to do with my keyboard. Is there some other way to trigger mirror display mode, or is there a way to get this keyboard to send the right signal to OSX so it will work?

Comment: Try F7 please - does it work?

Comment: Nope. None of the F keys do anything except for Cmd+F5 which opens VoiceOver.